# Quaternionic matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, quaternions

What would be the correct way to multiply matrices with quaternionic values in Mathematica?
For example

```
<< Quaternions`
{{Quaternion[7, 0, 0, 0], 
  Quaternion[0, 1, 1, 0]}, {Quaternion[0, 0, 1, 7], 
  Quaternion[0, 5, 0, 1]}}
(*Both %.% and %**% seem to not be correct*)
```

Comment: Denoting `q = {{Quaternion[7, 0, 0, 0], 
     Quaternion[0, 1, 1, 0]}, {Quaternion[0, 0, 1, 7], 
     Quaternion[0, 5, 0, 1]}}`, then ``Internal`InheritedBlock[{Times},
Times//Attributes={Flat,Listable,NumericFunction,OneIdentity,Protected};
q . q/.{Times->NonCommutativeMultiply}
] `` and `Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply,q,q]//TensorContract[#,{{2,3}}]&` should both give the matrix product `q.q`.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a new function that multiplies quaternion matrices like:

```
qmatmul[q1_, q2_] := Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, q1, q2, Plus]
```

Let us test this by:

```
q = {{Quaternion[7, 0, 0, 0], Quaternion[0, 1, 1, 0]}, 
     {Quaternion[0, 0, 1, 7], Quaternion[0, 5, 0, 1]}};

qmatmul[q, q]

(* Out:
{{Quaternion[48, 7, -7, 1], Quaternion[-5, 8, 6, -5]},
 {Quaternion[-7, -1, -28, 54], Quaternion[-27, -7, 7, -1]}} *)
```

To check if this is correct, we may do the same calculation by "hand". The non-commuting can be simulated by choosing elements that are lexicographic in the correct order (e.g. $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$):

```
ta = {{a11, a12}, {a21, a22}}; 
tb = {{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}};
ta . tb /. {Times -> NonCommutativeMultiply, x_^2 -> x ** x} /. 
  Thread[Flatten@ta -> Flatten@q] /. Thread[Flatten@tb -> Flatten@q]

(* Out: 
{{Quaternion[48, 7, -7, 1], Quaternion[-5, 8, 6, -5]}, 
 {Quaternion[-7, -1, -28, 54], Quaternion[-27, -7, 7, -1]}} *)
```

We see that it is indeed correct.