# Quaternionic Kronecker Product

Tags: matrix, quaternions

I want to define the Kronecker product of quaternionic matrices.
I want to follow the idea of this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273285/18862) of passing the `NonCommutativeMultiply` to the matrix product

```
times[q1_, q2_] := Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, q1, q2, Plus]
```

As the standard `KroneckerProduct` does not allow to change the definition of its matrix multiplication I am attempting something like

```
Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, q1, q2] // ArrayFlatten[#, 2] &
```

But this does not work as hoped.

Comment: For future reference, please show the actual vs. desired output of your code, rather than saying "didn't work as hoped", so we know exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 7):

You could temporarily and locally change the "meaning" of `Times` to `NonCommutativeMultiply` just while you run `KroneckerProduct`:

```
Block[
 {Times = NonCommutativeMultiply},
 KroneckerProduct[Array[b, {2, 2}], Array[a, {2, 2}]]
]

(* Out:
{{b[1, 1] ** a[1, 1], b[1, 1] ** a[1, 2], b[1, 2] ** a[1, 1], b[1, 2] ** a[1, 2]},
 {b[1, 1] ** a[2, 1], b[1, 1] ** a[2, 2], b[1, 2] ** a[2, 1], b[1, 2] ** a[2, 2]},
 {b[2, 1] ** a[1, 1], b[2, 1] ** a[1, 2], b[2, 2] ** a[1, 1], b[2, 2] ** a[1, 2]},
 {b[2, 1] ** a[2, 1], b[2, 1] ** a[2, 2], b[2, 2] ** a[2, 1], b[2, 2] ** a[2, 2]}}
*)
```

Comment: Nice answer, indeed!

Comment: Why are you inheriting the default definition of `Times`? After all, you are overriding most things anyway. Also, you are inheriting the `Orderless` attribute - that shouldn't matter here, since `Times` is immediately replaced my `NonVommutativeMultiply`, but I would be a bit worried about the evaluator canonicalizing the expression before replacing the head.

Comment: Nevermind, it does matter: If you swap `a` and `b`, you still get `a[...]**b[...]` type products with the current answer

Comment: @Lukas You have a good point. I went with `InheritedBlock` out of habit, but `Block` should actually do fine here, and it's simpler. That also returns `b ** a`  products when swapping a and b. See update

Answer (score 5):

Again, a possible solution is to define a new function.

```
qkronecker[q1_, q2_] := Outer[NonCommutativeMultiply, q1, q2] // ArrayFlatten
```

To see if this works, we first try not with quaternions, but with symbols:

```
am = Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {2, 2}];
bm = Array[Subscript[b, #1, #2] &, {2, 2}];

qkronecker[am, bm] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Now with quaternions:

```
q = {{Quaternion[7, 0, 0, 0], 
    Quaternion[0, 1, 1, 0]}, {Quaternion[0, 0, 1, 7], 
    Quaternion[0, 5, 0, 1]}};

qkronecker[q, q] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: I was about posting the same idea... ^^